# I need to get a checkbox already checked with angular material

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, angular-material

I have this code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Estado">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Estado</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="">
        <mat-checkbox *ngIf=!state mat-checked></mat-checkbox>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

When the condition in the `*ngIf` is met the checkbox appears unchecked, but I need to get it already checked, I don't know how, hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mat-checkbox component has a input called 'checked'

Try something like that:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Estado"> 
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Estado</th> 
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="">
    <mat-checkbox *ngIf="!state" [checked]="true"></mat-checkbox>
  </td> 
</ng-container>
```

It's always a good idea to check the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api) tab in the documentation of the component you are using

Answer (score 1):

You need an `ngModel` to with a variable set to true if you want the checkbox to default in as true. Then, if you ever check/uncheck the checkbox, the current true/false value will be saved in your variable

ts

```
estadoFlag: boolean = true;
```

html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Estado">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Estado</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="">
        <mat-checkbox *ngIf=!state [(ngModel)]="estadoFlag"></mat-checkbox>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```